# Rails, pulling complicated logic out of views

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a view that is getting complicated, and I'm wondering I should be doing this different? Picture (or code) is worth a 1000 words, so heres the view...

```
    <% @orientation_by_date[date].each do |orientation| %>
      <% if current_user %>
        <% if orientation.active? %>
          <li><%= link_to orientation.class_time, new_orientation_registration_path(orientation) %>
              (<%= orientation.current_number_seats %>/<%= orientation.seats %>)</li>
        <% else %>
          <li><%= orientation.class_time %>(Class full)</li>
        <% end %>
        <%= link_to "VIEW", orientation_registrations_path(orientation) %></li>
      <% else %>
        <% if orientation.active? %>
          <li><%= link_to orientation.class_time, new_orientation_registration_path(orientation) %>
              (<%= orientation.current_number_seats %>/<%= orientation.seats %>)</li>
        <% elsif orientation.class_date.before Date.today %>
          <li><%= orientation.class_time %>(Class Closed)</li>
        <% end %>
        <% else %>
          <li><%= orientation.class_time %>(Class full)</li>
        <% end %>
      <% end %>
    <% end %>
```

What you are looking at is a the front end calendar view of a scheduling application. Based on differnt states, you see different information in each day on the calendar, ie, the number of seats remaining, vs. 'Class Full' vs. something else for Admins. Should I be pulling this logic into my model or controller somehow?

Comment: Needless to say, although it sounds obvious, use helpers to clean it up a bit, because it does help things look tidier and eliminates repeated code. Also consider using a templating language like haml or slim (I use slim). Use more  spacing as well. Many lines in the first section and second section (has user or doesn't have user) are identical, so try experimenting with changing the logic a bit; perhaps that the main condition would be `if active?`, not `if current_user`, or something like that. define a `display_class_time` method in the helper, instead of repeating code and conditions.

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of ways to skin the cat.  Which is 'right' is as much about personal preferences as anything else.  That said, here are a few ideas that you might want to consider.

**Use partials for each type of user**
This may or may not be your driving concern but the outermost layer of decision making is based on user type so it may make sense to build a partial for each type of user.  In this case you might have 'active_user_orientation_view' and 'guest_orientation_view'.  Doing that reduces (this section) of your view down to a single if-then-else statement with pretty clear indication of your intent -- registered users see one thing and guests see something else.

**Wrap-up repeating code into helper methods**
Two of the list items are generated using the exact same code.  Make it DRY!  As an example, I'd probably drop down into the OrientationsHelper (app/helpers/orientations_helper.rb) and add a #orientation_full_item helper like this

```
def orientation_full_item(orientation)
  content_tag(:li) do
    "#{orientation.class_time} (Class full)"
  end
end
```

With that helper in place, the two lines rendering the "Class full" message could be reduced to <%= orientation_full_item(orientation) %>.  You could do the same for the list item that provides a link to the registration form.  For consistency, you might do it for all of the list items.  That would give you a view that very clearly declares its intentions.

**Consider using a Presenter**
Rather than litter your model (business logic) with view-oriented convenience methods, a better choice would be to create a new class that accepts an instance of the class and provides the same convenience methods.  This is what the Presenter pattern is all about.  The advantage of it is that you very clearly organize your code along the lines of it's intention -- biz logic stays together and stays untangled from view logic.  In this case you might provide an ActiveUserOrientationPresenter and a GuestOrientationPresenter class, each of which provides a #list_item convenience method capable of rendering out the list item with its appropriate contents.

The PragProg guys have a title written by Bruce Williams with some great suggestions on how to build robust view code that is probably worth the money and time invested.  One of the available code snippets deals specifically with presenters.  You can read it http://media.pragprog.com/titles/warv/present.pdf.

Answer (score -1):

Write unit tests that nail down the contents of all those `<li>` items with XPath.

Grab `Nokogiri`, and use `Nokogiri::HTML::Builder` to write all that in Ruby:

```
builder = Nokogiri::HTML::Builder.new do |doc|
   doc.ul {
     doc.li('data 1')
     doc.li('data 2') if oodles_of_poodles?
     doc.li('data 3')
   }
end

puts builder.to_html
```

Now that it's all in one language, you can refactor it freely without constantly tripping over the escape tokens needed to mix two languages together.

Comment: ??? I was not asking about tests. I'm asking if there is a better way to refactor my view by possibly moving some of the logic to the controller or model.

Comment: Unlike with HAML (a _third_ language), if you convert your HTML to Builder notation, you can refactor individual bits of the Ruby code out into the model. Or all of it, or just the `if` statements, and so on...