# How to rewrite this Ruby to be DRYer and conform better to Rails' best practice

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm fairly sure I've broken some best practises here, could anyone give me some guidance as to where this code should go. If it can't be improved (unlikely) please tell me too :)

```
<% year = '' %>
<% for activity in @activities %>
  <% if activity.date.strftime('%Y') == year %>
    <%= activity.date.strftime('%d %h') %>
    <%= activity.desc %>
    <br/>
  <% else %>
    <% year = activity.date.strftime('%Y') %>
    <%= year %>
    <br/>
    <%= activity.date.strftime('%d %h') %>
    <%= activity.desc %>
    <br/>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

The aim is to list all the activities in each year under a year "header". I'll tidy up the output later...

The controller simply proves @activities with Activity.all

EDIT: I understand the need for a helper but is it acceptable to add html to a helper, or do i need to do this in the view?

Comment: Why not simply ``<%= activity.date.strftime('%Y') %>`` just for a start

Comment: @DennyMueller that does not create a single `year` header for all activities in the same year.

Comment: I don't really see for loops much in ruby. Why not use the `each` method?

Comment: True, I'll switch to each in a bit.

Answer (score 1):

Write automated tests that cover those branches, then refactor to move that code into a helper method, and DRY it:

```
def format_dates(activities)
  year = 0
  activities.map do |activity|
    activity_stuff = activity.date.strftime('%d %h ') + activity.desc
    if activity.date.year == year
      activity_stuff
    else
      year = activity.date.year
      [ activity.date.strftime('%Y'),
       activity_stuff ]
    end
  end.flatten
end
```

Now the HTML.ERB code is just this:

```
<%=raw format_dates(@activities).join('<br/>') %>
```

Remember the rubric "smart models, thin controllers, and dumb views" - the helper is really model-side; you could also make that code a static method of `Activity`.

Comment: If I wanted to put a div around each year group would it be acceptable to put the html in the helper file or would I need to do something else?

Comment: It's `raw`, so just use `activity.date.strftime('<div class="year_header">%Y</div>')`. That's why `strftime` uses `%`, so you can play with their strings however you need.

Comment: I think he means each year group (the activities for year X), not place the year by itself in a div. I don't think that would be very easy to do with this solution.

Answer (score 0):

The code that is common for both `if` and `else` should not be present in either, so you don't have to repeat yourself there.

```
<% year = '' %>
<% for activity in @activities %>
  <% unless activity.date.strftime('%Y') == year %>
    <% year = activity.date.strftime('%Y') %>
    <%= year %>
    <br/>
  <% end %>
  <%= activity.date.strftime('%d %h') %>
  <%= activity.desc %>
  <br/>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Please don't use formatted values as a basis for comparison. Many date/time classes (e.g. [TimeWithZone](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/TimeWithZone.html)) have a `year` method or thereabouts that give you access to the year. You should use `strftime` for display, not for logic.
2. The moment you instantiate a variable in the view is the moment you know you probably should move this into a helper.

   ```
   def activities_header(activities)
     activities.group_by { |activity| activity.date.year }.each do |year, activities_by_year|
       concat year
       concat content_tag(:br)
       activities_by_year.each do |activity|
         concat activity.date.strftime('%d %h')
         concat activity.desc
         concat content_tag(:br)
       end
     end
   end
   ```

I haven't tested this, but the idea here is, group the activities by year to start with. You can then call this from your view with `<%= activities_header(activities) %>`.

Comment: Same question to you, if I wanted to put a div around each year group would it be acceptable to put the html in the helper file or would I need to do something else?

Comment: I suspect in modern rails that answer needs a `raw`, unless `concat` handles it. But your question has the same answer as for my version; see above. And a third option is Nokogiri::HTML::Builder, such as the incorrectly down-voted answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19729583/rails-pulling-complicated-logic-out-of-views/19730426#19730426

Comment: @user3052988 You can use content_tag for the div too, as content_tag takes a block. I'd suggest putting the HTML in the helper, as you don't want the structure of the helper dependent on the markup in the view and vice versa; keep the activities_header in one place, the helper.

Comment: @Phlip I'm pretty sure that content_tag returns an escaped string, and that concat here appends to a SafeBuffer. If you mix regular strings with safe strings, then you're right, you'll need to raw/html_safe your markup. This is NOT the same as your answer, though; your answer creates a dependency between the helper (returning an array) and the view (joining an array with <br>) that shouldn't exist. If you're using a helper to handle the activities header, put all the markup there, not some of it. I'd also avoid bringing in Nokogiri as it creates an additional dependency which isn't necessary.

Comment: violent agreement achieved; my fix illustrated a "first pass" of a refactoring. Subsequent passes will depend on forces only the OP can see.